# How to scrapy a ip address instead of a url for Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to use an IP address in place of the `url` parameter for `scrapy` spiders? Below is what it would look like ideally:

```
yield scrapy.Request(ipaddress = x.x.x.x, callback=callbackCode)
```

Comment: What is the output when you use an IP address?

Comment: raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
    ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: x.x.x.x

Comment: What about if you use "http://" before x.x.x.x and set that as the url?

Comment: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.

Comment: Are you really kidding? Do you even have an idea the difference between what IP address is and what a web page is? In simple words, an IP address points to a server which serves websites which can contain multiple webpages. And scraping is for scraping data from webpages. A server can contain any data other than webpages.